# Mypy error: "Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader"

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to understand how to use the overload decorator when typing functions.  If I write the following code and run it through mypy:

```
from typing import Union, overload

@overload
def myfunc(a: float, b: float) -> float: ...
@overload
def myfunc(a: int, b: int) -> int: ...

def myfunc(a: Union[float, int], b: Union[float, int]) -> Union[float, int]:
    return a + b
```

Then I get a "error: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)"

I don't understand why the parameter types of signature 1 (ie. floats) are broader that signature 2 (ie. ints).

What is going on here?

Comment: This is complicated by the fact that `mypy` treats `int` and `float` in a special way... basically, `int` will match `float`. So your second signature will never be matched

Comment: See: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/duck_type_compatibility.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mypy has a weird special case that treats `int` as valid where `float` is expected, because requiring people to write `Union[int, float]` all over the place would have been awkward enough to seriously hinder adoption of type annotations. That means `myfunc(1, 2)` matches both signatures.

When multiple signatures of an overloaded function match a call, mypy will pick the signature defined first. With the way you've written your code, it's impossible for mypy to pick the `int` signature. The `float` signature will *always* be picked for any call.

You can fix this by putting the `int` signature first:

```
@overload
def myfunc(a: int, b: int) -> int: ...
@overload
def myfunc(a: float, b: float) -> float: ...
```

Comment: didn't realize that the method definition order would make any difference, thanks a lot, also for the explanation!